# Will an empty class be optimized away

Tags: c++, optimization

Say I have the following class:

```
class A{ };
```

And then in my code I have a function:

```
A foo(){
  A ret;
  //Do stuff
  return ret;
}
```

And then I use the function later....

Will an optimizing compiler (like `g++`) just treat `foo()` like a `void` function and skip actually allocating memory for the empty object? It might not do this because even an empty class has a size of 1.

Comment: Even if it can't (semantically) be optimized away, it may be returned in a register. In which case, why do you care if it's optimized away or not?

Comment: @StoryTeller Because I want to know if returning an empty class is hurting me over returning void

Comment: Hurting you how? It's not as fast as simply omitting a return value, sure. But it hardly seems like a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Why not just try it and see?   https://godbolt.org/g/XusxGE  The color codes in the source match the color codes in the generated asm.  But really, either you really care about this in which case you can hand code it, or you don't in which case just let the compiler do its thing and don't worry about it.   If you don't know if you care, benchmark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a use case for [gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/C9XO4Y) where you can see what assembler code is generated (I recommend you click the colourize button to see which C++ code corresponds to which assembler code). You can see that even with -O0 there is no code generated to allocate or copy the object. You can try with other compilers and optimization levels. You can use `#define`s to easily compare the code between returning `class A` and `void`.

Comment: @DarthRubik consider looking at the generated assembly on the actual platform you are working on